# How to calculate the probability that the maximum of two independent standard normal distributions is greater than zero?

Tags: normal-distribution, self-study

The R command `hist(pmax(rnorm(10),rnorm(10)))` gives a histogram of random variable Y, where Y is the maximum observation of two independent Gaussians.

- How can I mathematically determine the probability that Y is greater than zero?
- How can I use a simulation to determine the probability that Y is greater than zero?

Comment: I retagged the question as homework, please remove the tag if this is not the case.

Comment: I've modified the question to make this question read less like a homework question

Comment: @charles: what have you tried and where are you stuck? **Hint**: There is a great amount of symmetry in this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple simulation in R:

```
> set.seed(4444)
> k=1e+7; mean(pmax(rnorm(k), rnorm(k)) > 0)
[1] 0.7502026
```

- `set.seed` makes the simulation replicable
- by making `k` a very large number, the simulation approaches the true value (although if you were being thorough, you'd quantify the uncertainty of your estimate)
- `mean` on a vector of logical data gives the proportion `TRUE`
- `rnorm` defaults to mean = 0, sd =1 (i.e., standard normal)
- the logical condition is that the maximum (`pmax`) of the two random standard normal variables is greater than zero  (`> 0`).

Answer (score 2):

#### How can I mathematically determine the probability that Y is greater than zero?

$P(x_1>0) + P(x_2>0) -P(x_1>0)\times P(x_2>0)$  or use the complement : $1-P(x_1<0)\times P(x_2<0)$ ... I think.. LOL

#### How can I use a simulation to determine the probability that Y is greater than zero?

Have you tried?